# What include directory do I link to for OpenGL in a distributable project?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

I plan on making an OpenGL C++ program that I can run on any PC. I'm used to setting adding the additional dependencies beforehand and setting up the 'Includes' path for the program to find all the .h files I need.

What do I about the includes directory if I want to run the exe on a PC without that path? Normally it would be:

Desktop/VisualStudioDevelopmentLibraries/Includes

and the program could find them in there, but on another PC, they would not have that path!

Comment: ... so what? Including headers and such is part of *compilation*. Once you have a compiled executable, compilation is over. So header inclusions don't matter.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, so I can just link all the includes before hand on my PC and then give it out (as a release build?) to another PC and that will work? That makes a lot of sense now. What about static linking too btw - I did notice that when I read around. I that necessary?

Comment: The big concern is with linking.  You might need the redestributable runtime.

Comment: I'm very new to this - what is that?

Comment: Basically, when you write a C++ program with Visual Studio, there's an extra piece of code (the runtime library) that you need to give people before they can run your project, unless you change the settings on your project to include that code in your executable (static runtime library).